# How to properly detect whether a define/variable in m4 is empty while it can include commas?

Tags: m4

How can I detect in m4 template whether define/variable is empty while it also can contain commas? It's passed through m4 arguments, so it can contain any value.

Problem is that when I write the `ifelse` condition without putting the variable inside quotes, it works, but when the var contains commas, it breaks the template. If I put it inside quotes, empty string won't get detected.

**Example #1**:

File template.m4:

```
ifelse(`_VAR_', `', `empty; "_VAR_"', `non-empty; "_VAR_"')
```

Results:

```
$ m4 -D _VAR_=text template.m4
non-empty; "text"
$ m4 -D _VAR_="a, a, INJECTED" template.m4
non-empty; "a, a, INJECTED"
```

These are ok.

```
$ m4 -D _VAR_= template.m4
non-empty; ""
$ m4 -D _VAR_="" template.m4
non-empty; ""
```

Problem, expected: `empty; ""` (in both cases).

**Example #2**:

File template.m4:

```
ifelse(_VAR_, `', `empty; "_VAR_"', `non-empty; "_VAR_"')
```

Results:

```
$ m4 -D _VAR_=test template.m4
non-empty; "test"
$ m4 -D _VAR_= template.m4
empty; ""
$ m4 -D _VAR_="" template.m4
empty; ""
```

These are ok.

```
$ m4 -D _VAR_="a, a, INJECTED" template.m4
INJECTED
```

Wasn't handled correctly, expected: `non-empty; "a, a, INJECTED"`

**My environment**

- OS: Xubuntu 18.04 LTS 64bit
- m4: 1.4.18

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the following will be your desire:

```
ifelse(defn(`_VAR_'),`',`empty',`non empty: _VAR_')
```